# Advanced algebra practice

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I just worked through an equation where I was left with 
$$
a^2+2xab+x^2b^2= a^2+6ab+yb^2+yb^2.
$$

In order to solve this equation I know I was able to set the corresponding parts equal since the whole expression is equal. I was just wondering what type of question this method would fall under, meaning in what type of question would someone have to use this approach to solve for the answer. Can someone give me an example question? Thank you!

Comment: Are you saying that you have: $a^2 = a^2 \rightarrow 1 = 1$, $2xab = 6ab \rightarrow 2x = 6$, and $x^2b^2 = 2yb^2 \rightarrow x^2 = 2y^2$ (which would lead to $x = 3$ then $ 9 = 2y^2 \rightarrow y = \pm\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}$)?  This is a common approach when doing polynomial long division as well as when solving differential equations involving polynomials.

Comment: yeah exactly. I'm trying to find practice questions of that sort where you need to use that approach to solve but I can't see to figure out what to search?

Comment: One simple example is with partial fraction decomposition (which is often overlooked).  Example $\frac{1}{1-x^2} = \frac{a}{1 + x} + \frac{b}{1 - x}$.  If we work it backwards we find that the numerator is $1 = a(1 - x) + b(1 + x) = a + b - ax + bx = (a + b) + (b - a)x$.  To solve we set corresponding "parts" equal.  The constant should be $1$ thus $a + b = 1$ and the $x$-part should be zero thus $b - a = 0 \rightarrow a = b$.  Now we can solve: $a + a = 1 \rightarrow a = b = \frac{1}{2}$: $\frac{1}{1-x^2} = \frac{1}{2(1+x)} + \frac{1}{2(1-x)}$.

Comment: Ah very true and very nice! I was looking for something more at the high school level though.

Answer (score 0):

OK, at the high school level then this approach will help you understand polynomial long division.  Let's look at an example (hopefully not too trivial):

$$
\frac{x^4 - 3x^2 + 2x - 1}{x^2 - 1}
$$

You can certainly robotically learn the algorithm for performing this division...or you can understand what's going on via equalling corresponding parts.  First, look at the degree of the two polynomials: $4$ and $2$ therefore when you divide them, you should get a degree $2$ polynomial, therefore the following rational function can be written as follows:

$$
\frac{x^4 - 3x^2+2x-1}{x^2-1} = ax^2 + bx + c + \frac{dx + e}{x^2 - 1}
$$

Now it's a "simple" matter of finding $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, and $e$ (notice the quotes--it's simple but requires a lot of algebra).  We multiply this entire equation by $x^2 - 1$ then we would get the following:

$$
x^4-3x^2+2x-1 = (ax^2+bx+c)(x^2-1) + dx+e
$$

Multiply out the right side:

\begin{align}
(ax^2+bx+c)(x^2-1) =&\ ax^4 + bx^3 + cx^2 - ax^2 - bx - c \\
=&\ ax^4 + bx^3 + (c - a)x^2 - bx - c
\end{align}

Now combine that with $dx + e$:

\begin{align}
ax^4 + bx^3 + (c - a)x^2 - bx - c + dx +e =&\ ax^4 + bx^3 + (c - a)x^2 + (d -b)x + (e-c)
\end{align}

Finally you have the *full* equation:

\begin{align}
x^4-3x^2+2x-1=&\ ax^4 + bx^3 + (c - a)x^2 + (d -b)x + (e-c)
\end{align}

Now set corresponding parts equal:

\begin{align}
x^4 \rightarrow&\ 1 = a \\
x^3 \rightarrow&\ 0 = b \\
x^2 \rightarrow&\ -3 = c -a \\
x \rightarrow&\ 2 = d - b \\
1 \rightarrow&\ -1 = e - c
\end{align}

In this case we right away know that $a = 1$ and $b = 0$.  We then use that do find $c$:

$$
-3 = c - 1 \rightarrow c = -2
$$

Then:

$$
2 = d - 0 \rightarrow d = 2
$$

Finally:

$$
-1 = e - -2 \rightarrow e = -3
$$

Finally, this gives, now that we know that $a = 1$, $b = 0$, $c = -2$, $d = 2$, and $e = -3$:

$$
\frac{x^4 - 3x^2 + 2x - 1}{x^2 - 1} = x^2 - 2 + \frac{2x-3}{x^2-1 }
$$